# Full Data on Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv, timestamp

I have exported the Data from SQL Database. And one of the column contains Timestamp in the format 19/09/2016 05:58:07. But, when exported to CSV, the format I'm getting in the column is 58:07.

Please suggest me how to go about it

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database**. SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, there is a table created created here. And i'm exporting that table as a CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch that you are viewing the exported CSV file in Excel and this is where you're seeing the bad datetime format.

Please open your file in a text editor (such as Notepad) and see if the timestamp is in the correct format. If it is correct here, all you need to do is tell Excel to display it in a more appropriate format.

This you can do by

1. Selecting the cells or column containing your timestamp values
2. Right click the selection
3. Click `Format cells`
4. Under the `Number` tab, select the `Custom` format as category and enter the format `dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss` in the `type` textbox to get the format you provided.